# How can I add a custom variable to Sqitch, to be used in target postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqitch

I would like to add few variables:"username' and "database" in my sqitch.conf on a defined target.

file sqitch.conf=>

```
    engine = pg

[core "variables"]
    username = jv_root
    database = test

[target "dev_1"]
        uri = db:pg://username@sqlhost:5432/database

[target "dev_2"]
        uri = db:pg://username@sqlhost2:5432/database
```

where I run:
sqitch deploy -t dev_1
it throw an error =>
ERROR:  no such user: username

Answer (score 0):

You can add environment specific variables like this.

```
[target.dev_1.variables]
  username = jv_root
  password = test
```

How you address them in your sql files depends on the sql dialect.